# Sci Fi Short story about a prison with just one prisoner?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

i read it in a paperback story collection that I purchased new around 2006 to 2008, possibly themed as time travel or alternate realities.

For most of the story, we do not know who the prisoner is, but it is a high security place. I think it may be written from the perspective of the warden talking to a new guard, but not positive about this.

The premise was that at a future time, they had access to some type of time travel but also the world was heading to self destruction. Somehow the question is, if you could go back in time and take ONE prisoner in order to save the future of the world, who would it be.

Comment: By the end of the story, do you find out who the prisoner is? Is the prisoner a real person from our history? Do you remember who it is?

Comment: Do you remember anything about the other stories in the collection? Or perhaps the collection itself: title, cover art etc.?

Comment: I remember being deeply affected by the story and by finding out who the prisoner was, but now cannot recall the answer.

Comment: The collection of short stories were probably alternate reality stories, paperback and newly published when purchased in mid 2000s.  Maybe the back cover had a one sentence synopsis of each story in the book.

Comment: As far as who the prisoner was...Jesus comes to mind, but that could have been just who I was guessing and not necessarily who it really was.

Comment: The premise seems similar to Ursula K. Le Guin's short story, ["The Ones Who Walk Away from Omelas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ones_Who_Walk_Away_from_Omelas).